# Is it possible to use squid as a proxy gateway to other proxies?

Tags: proxy, squid

**CONTEXT:**

I have a number of proxies that I use for different purposes (scraping, price collection, etc.)

Some of these I own (e.g. a cloud server in a datacentre running squid), some of these are provided by 3rd party providers.  Many different applications use these proxies.  I want to easily switch between them, by having all my applications use a single proxy which then routes the requests to other proxies.

**QUESTION:**

Is it possible to configure a single proxy server using squid (or other software) that acts as a gateway and then based on certain parameters (e.g. target URL, proxy user, etc.) makes a decision regarding which secondary proxy to route the request to?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible by using `acl` and  `cache_peer` .

A simple example .

https://blog.hqcodeshop.fi/archives/365-Real-word-Squid-HTTP-proxy-hierarchy-setup-Expat-guide.html